# Firefox-esr wont proxy to burpsuite on tails os

Tags: firefox

Burpsuite Community Edition on Tails 5.11

- Firefox-esr proxy settings has warning 'Connections to localhost, 127.0.0.1/8, and ::1 are never proxied'.

I cannot find any mention of the error anywhere. Regardless of burpsuite settings (which are always valid I just change the port) firefox always says proxy server is refusing connections which makes me think its never getting out of firefox but I have no idea how to get around this.